# how to have a pop up contact form on submit display a confirmation message in the popup?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, onsubmit

I'm having great issues making this contact form that can be seen on the below visual. What I want the contact form to do is display on submit a thank you message or a message of confirmation instead of redirecting to the contact.php file where there isn't any styles you can see this in action on the provided link.

I've found some information that I can do this with Jquery Ajax that I've also tried displayed below, but I still can't seem to get it to work on submit to show a message in the pop up.

Does anyone know an easier way to do this or maybe point me in the right direction as this is something that I've been trying to fix for god knows how long.

Thank you for any help

Visual: 
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/index.html

PHP & HTML:

```
<?php
        $your_email = "maxlynn@madaxedesign.co.uk";
        $subject = "Email From Madaxe";
        $empty_fields_message = "<p>Please go back and complete all the fields in the form.</p>";
        $thankyou_message = "<p>Thank you. Your message has been sent. We Will reply as soon as possible.</p>";

        $name = stripslashes($_POST['txtName']);
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $message = stripslashes($_POST['txtMessage']);

        if (!isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

        ?>
        <form id="submit_message" class="hide_900" method="post" action="/contact.php" onsubmit="javascript: doSubmit();">
            <div id="NameEmail"> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtName">Name*</label> 
                    <input type="text" title="Enter your name" name="txtName" />
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <label for="txtEmail">Email*</label> 
                    <input  type="text" title="Enter your email address" name="txtEmail" />
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="MessageSubmit">
                <div> 
                    <textarea maxlength="1200" title="Enter your message" name="txtMessage"></textarea> 
                    <label for="txtMessage">Message</label>
                </div>
                <div class="submit"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
```

Jquery:

```
function doSubmit(){
  var postData = jQuery('#submit_message').serialize();    

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/contact.php',
    data: postData
  }).done(function( html ) {
    alert(html);
  });
```

Comment: Wow loving the result of all the help guys

Comment: Don't forget to mark the best answer to help other people looking for the same type of questions ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `return false`; at the end of your doSubmit function or the following code to prevent the form to redirect the user to the action page.

```
var doSubmit = function (event) {
  var postData = jQuery('#submit_message').serialize();    

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/contact.php',
    data: postData
  }).done(function( html ) {
    alert(html);
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}

$(function () {
    $('#submit_message').submit(doSubmit);
});
```

Modified HTLM

```
<form id="submit_message">
...
</form>
```

**What is this code doing ?**

First, we are defining a function to submit the form data.
Notice the event argument in the function. The first variable in this function is all the form values serialized in a ajax-complient request string. The `.ajax()` function is sending all the datas to your server. Note that as you did not set the type argument in the `.ajax()` function, the data are going to be send using the GET HTTP method.
Finally, `event.preventDefault()` prevents the submit event to be triggered in the browser. When the browser detect a submit event, it will try to submit the form based on the `action` and the `method` parameters in the `<form>` html tag. Usually, this submission performs an user redirection to the `action` page. This `event.preventDefault()` will disable this redirection. Note that the event argument is going to be set automatically by jQuery.

Last part, the `$(function() { ... });` part means "execute this part when the document is fully loaded." It ensures that the element with `sumbit_message` id exists before calling the `.submit()` method. This last method is an event binder. It means that when the submit event is fired on the `submit_message` form, the function `doSubmit` will be called.

I hope you have a better understanding of this script. This is a pretty basic one, but if you understand clearly the mechanics, it will help you do become a better jQuery programmer. :)

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TCffC/)

Comment: Is #myform meant to be the same as #submit_message?

Comment: Wish I understood Jquery better. Do you mind explaining what this script does and why? at the moment it just closes the contact and doesn't allow me to refresh the page and doesn't send the email. Any help would be great Thanks

Comment: @Maximus Robert Kenway LynnI've updated my post with explications about the script.

Comment: Wow, Thanks pdegand59 couldn't of asked for a better explanation. Yea I am rather new to Jquery so bit of a learning curve at the moment but sure I'll get that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.<form onsubmit='confirm()'>
function confirm()
{
alert("Thank You");
}
```

2.in contact.php call the page that is displayed again

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default event of the form. To do this, add the `e.preventDefault();` function to the top of your function in order to prevent this event from firing.

Also notice that we are passing the `e` parameter to your function. This represents the event that has been fired.

```
function doSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var postData = jQuery('#submit_message').serialize();    

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/contact.php',
    data: postData
  }).done(function( html ) {
    alert(html);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change your form with

```
<form id="submit_message" class="hide_900" method="post">
```

and in script put it

```
$("#submit_message").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //call your ajax
});
```

Comment: This seems not to work, it does close the popup however on the close but doesn't sent the email or show a thank you message. http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/index.html